# New commands having variable numbers of parameters and being used in subscripts

Tags: macros, subscripts

Is it possible to make the last two cases work without the need in wrapping the command calls in curly brackets?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\def\command{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\commandOne}{\commandNone}}
\def\commandOne#1{{\boldsymbol#1}}
\def\commandNone{{\boldsymbol\alpha}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \title{Cases}
  \maketitle

  \section*{Case 1}
  $\command$

  \section*{Case 2}
  $\command{\beta}$

  \section*{Case 3}
  $A_{\command}$ % <--- WANTED: $A_\command$

  \section*{Case 4}
  $A_{\command{\beta}}$ % <--- WANTED: $A_\command{\beta}$
\end{document}
```

If I remove the curly brackets, I get the following error:

```
! Missing { inserted.
```

Thank you!

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to leave out the `{}`-part. Some packages even require it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's possible, at the expense of adding `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. But I would recommend neither avoiding the braces nor defining a command with an optional braced argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\command{\bgroup\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\commandOne}{\commandNone}}
\def\commandOne#1{\boldsymbol{#1}\egroup}
\def\commandNone{\boldsymbol\alpha}\egroup}
\makeatother
```

But don't do this, it is much better to make the braces explicit, also don't make optional arguments take `{` delimited macros. LaTeX goes to a lot of effort to try to give commands consistent syntax and optional arguments should be `[]` delimited.

so

```
\newcommand\command[1][\alpha]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
```

and

```
\command[\beta]
```

Comment: Also `\bm` is better than `\boldsymbol`. `;-)`

Comment: Regarding optional arguments, it was the only solution I knew, but I certainly prefer to do everything the right way, so I am switching to what you suggested, including explicit braces. Thank you all)